# Android queue for API requests

Tags: android, queue, vk

I'm writing a client for VK social network on android. This social network allows to do only 2-3 requests per second, and when i adding some requests to different methods, i'm getting exceptions eg. "Too much requests per second"

So my question is: how to make a queue of api requests, with ability to set priority for each request.

Thx in advance!

Comment: @GabeSechan, thanks for your response. I tried to understand how does PriorityQueue works, but I'm not understood. If u can explain this to me, that would be cool! Txh in advance!

Comment: It's a collection.  YOu use offer() to add an item to it, peek() to get the highest priority in it, and poll() to get the highest priority item and remove it.  It uses a Comparator that you can define to compare priorities.

Comment: @GabeSechan, okay I kinda understood. If I may, can u give my your email or hangouts or whatever so I'll be able to ask, if I won't be good with those queues? If no then no, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, because in my apps I tend to use a dedicated `AsyncTask` for each different type of server request.  So when I was reading this question, I was asking myself: how would I implement something like this when each task is a stand-alone component that doesn't know about the other tasks?

I could try to make a `PriorityQueue` like @GabeSechan said, but that means I would need a background thread dedicated to waiting for tasks to dequeue, then executing them while pacing the removal of queued tasks.  But this thread sounds like it would have to be a `Service`, so I would have to add all that infrastructure.  Then what about debugging multi-threading problems like hangs and race conditions, maybe even deadlocks?  No thank you.  There must be an easier way...

So I got to thinking... Throttling requests means that every request needs to happen at a certain time. What if instead of queuing the *requests*, you queued the *times*? What if you had a singleton that doles out time slots for requests?  It would work something like this:

- Start off by calling a method on the time slot dispenser to receive a time slot.  The time slot would be given in a milliseconds of delay from now when it is okay for the request to execute.
- If delay is greater than zero, call `Handler.postDelayed()` for the delay, with a Runnable containing the request logic
- After delay, Handler handles Runnable which starts `AsyncTask` or a background thread to process a request.

The logic for the time slot dispenser would look like this:

```
public static synchronized long getNextRequestDelay() {

    long delay = 0;
    long current = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
    if (current > sLastRequestTime + REQUEST_GAP_MILLIS) {
        //  we don't have any outstanding requests
        sLastRequestTime = current;
    } else {
        // figure out what the delay needs to be
        sLastRequestTime += REQUEST_GAP_MILLIS;
        delay = sLastRequestTime - current;
    }

    return delay;
}
```

Now, I wrote some code there, but I just typed it into the answer so I won't even claim it'll compile.  Not to mention that you should use a monotonic clock like `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` so that you're not affected by the user changing the clock time (Don't forget to multiply your GAP by 1000000).  But the main points are:

1. You have a single (i.e. static) place for the execution time of the most recent requesting task
2. You check that time and increment it every time you dispense a time slot
3. You need to synchronize access to the dispenser method.  (Okay, you may have to wrestle with deadlocks after all.)

It's simple. And I like simple.  I mean, I *really* like simple.

Comment: Kris, big thanks to you, but i need to figure out some positions
1) What is REQUEST_GAP_MILLIS
2) In my AsyncTask i should call getNextRequestDelay(), check if it equals or not to zero, and then sleep or not sleep my thread, right?

Comment: REQUEST_GAP_MILLIS would be the minimum number of milliseconds allowed between requests, so for example if you are only allowed 3 requests per second it would be 333.  Also, your understanding of how to use it is correct; get the value from the dispenser and if its zero request immediately, if non-zero then call Thread,sleep() with that value before requesting.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you will need to do things like keep a reference to any executing task and cancel it if the activity is stopped.

Comment: Okay, i set REQUEST_GAP_MILLIS to 333, sLastRequestTime is initializatin as 0 on app run, but getNextRequestDelay is always giving back  0 and i still receiving "Too much requests..."

Comment: Like REQUEST_GAP_MILLIS in all uppercase implying a final/constant value, beginning the sLastRequestTime with an "s" was meant to imply that it is a static value, so that it retains its value in between calls.  So whenever the dispenser method is called, it should have access to the timestamp of the previous call.

Comment: Yes, sLastRequestTime is static, and in debugger i see it keeping previous result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74821/discussion-between-dennes544-and-kris-larson).